# Anonymous User Log in with ActionMailer and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, lotus-domino

I have seen the RailsCasts video on setting up ActionMailer for Rails 3. However, I have a situation where the mail server (Lotus Notes) I need to use requires an anonymous login (where I do not put in a user name or password). I set up an initializer file, controller, and mailer information settings below. I am not getting any errors when I send the email and I can see the email being created and "sent" from the terminal; however, the email is not being delivered. What am I doing wrong?

Initializer File:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.home22.com",
   :port                 => 25,
   :domain               => "home22.com",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

Controller:

```
 def send_alert()
    @assessment = Assessment.first
    AlertMailer.alert_notice(@assessment).deliver 
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
       # format.html { render :action => (assessments_url) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
  end
```

Mailer:

```
class AlertMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default  :from => "Rails Application"
  def alert_notice(assessment)
    attachments["alert.csv"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/alert.csv")
    mail(:to => 'mcmahling@gmail.com', :subject => 'Alert')
  end
end
```

Comment: stupid question maybe, but did you restart te server?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information here to know what's really going on.  You should check what's been recorded in the log.nsf file on the Domino server, and if that doesn't give you enough information ere are a couple of IBM technotes ( https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003007  https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095102 ) that will help you set up to collect debug data that may help you get further along.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I'm not entirely sure *why* it works, but I have a guess.

When you set the smtp_settings hash, you replace the existing defaults.  This means that any default options you don't include simply don't exist in the hash.  If the hash is declared without a default object or block, it should return nil when anyone tries to access a non-present key (As [The Docs for Hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) specify).

You're not setting the `:authentication` option, so it should default to `nil` which is what you want.  But, obviously, that's not working so it's not relying on the default value for that hash (or is merging it into another hash with a preset default).

This part is the guess: Somewhere, the mailer code is checking for the presence of the key rather then the value it's linked too.  Finding it missing, it's using something else as a default.

Regardless of whether that's the cause, when was having the same problem, I specifically included `:authentication => nil` in the `smtp_settings` hash which resolved the issue.